# PHP foreach loop issue with first element

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to add `first` and `last` class to some `LI` elements and I'm having a problem with the first index. The code where I have the issue is here:

```
// this is always true, and all items get the `first` class
if ($i == 0) { $menu_item_class .= ' first'; }
```

The entire code looks like this:

```
function social_icons( $menu_item_class='', $icon_class='', $title_class = ''){
   $menu_item_class .= ($title_class != '') ? ' no-title' : '';
   $social_network = array(
     0=>  array (
       "title"=> "ello",
       "url"=>"envato"
     ),
     1=> array (
       "title"=> "vk",
       "url"=> "envato"
     ),
     2=> array (
       "title"=> "twitter",
       "url"=> "envato"
     ),
     3=> array (
       "title"=> "lastfm",
       "url"=> "envato"
     )
   ); 
   $social_icon_wrapper = ' string';
   $type = ' string2';
   $count = 4;

   if ( $count > 0 ) { ?>
   <div id="social-network">
       <ul class="social-icons">
       <?php foreach ($social_network as $i=>$sn ){
           // var_dump($i); // this always returns fine
           if ( $i == 0 ) { $menu_item_class .= ' first'; } // for some reason this IF is always true
           if ( $i == ($count-1) ) { $menu_item_class .= ' last'; } ?>
           <?php if ( $sn['title'] == 'ello' ) { ?> <li class="<?php echo $menu_item_class; ?>"><a class="ello" href="https://ello.co/<?php echo $sn['url']; ?>"><span class="social-icon-wrapper<?php echo $type; ?>"><i class="<?php echo $icon_class; ?> social-ello"></i></span>ello</a></li><?php } ?>
           <?php if ( $sn['title'] == 'vk' ) { ?> <li class="<?php echo $menu_item_class; ?>"><a class="vk" href="https://vk.com/<?php echo $sn['url']; ?>"><span class="social-icon-wrapper<?php echo $type; ?>"><i class="<?php echo $icon_class; ?> social-vk"></i></span>vk</a></li><?php } ?>
           <?php if ( $sn['title'] == 'facebook' ) { ?> <li class="<?php echo $menu_item_class; ?>"><a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/<?php echo $sn['url']; ?>"><span class="social-icon-wrapper<?php echo $type; ?>"><i class="<?php echo $icon_class; ?> social-facebook"></i></span>facebook</a></li><?php } ?>
           <?php if ( $sn['title'] == 'pinterest' ) { ?> <li class="<?php echo $menu_item_class; ?>"><a class="pinterest" href="https://pinterest.com/<?php echo $sn['url']; ?>"><span class="social-icon-wrapper<?php echo $type; ?>"><i class="<?php echo $icon_class; ?> social-pinterest"></i></span>pinterest</a></li><?php } ?>
           <?php if ( $sn['title'] == 'twitter' ) { ?> <li class="<?php echo $menu_item_class; ?>"><a class="twitter" href="https://www.twitter.com/<?php echo $sn['url']; ?>"><span class="social-icon-wrapper<?php echo $type; ?>"><i class="<?php echo $icon_class; ?> social-twitter"></i></span>twitter</a></li><?php } ?>
           <?php if ( $sn['title'] == 'lastfm' ) { ?> <li class="<?php echo $menu_item_class; ?>"><a class="lastfm" href="http://www.last.fm/user/<?php echo $sn['url']; ?>"><span class="social-icon-wrapper<?php echo $type; ?>"><i class="<?php echo $icon_class; ?> social-lastfm"></i></span>lastfm</a></li><?php } ?>
       <?php } ?>      
       </ul>
   </div>

   <?php } 
 }
 social_icons();
```

I made a simple [pen](http://codepad.viper-7.com/poZ3jU) to illustrate the issue. Please check and let me know what's wrong.

Comment: Isn't this because, once you set the variable it doesn't change for the next loop? (The `if` is only true once - you can `echo` to check that - but the value is set and not changed latter - the variable has now the value `.= ' first'`, right?)

Comment: You should check the code and the output of the pen.

Comment: The `first` class is set for all `LI`, while the `last` is set properly only for the last. @chris85 I just tried your solution to no avail.

Comment: Use another variable (set it's value to what's in `$class_name`) to keep track of the original value and just change that new var if needed. Did you understand the problem mentioned in my first comment? Look at the result, it adds `first` to the last one too.

Comment: After re-looking at this whole thing can be much simpler. Use dynamic values. Include your code here and you will probably get a better response. I dont have enough time now to help, sorry.

Comment: @chris85 please make a quick example, I don't know what you're talking about. I'm not very advanced.

Comment: Well, if you are just going to ignore my comments and not even care to respond, I'll move on to another question. You're the one asking...

Comment: @FirstOne I'm sorry, yes I don't understand your first comment.

Comment: @FirstOne I also tried something else like `if ( $i === ($count-1) ) { $firstLast = ' last'; }
   elseif ( $i === 0 ) { $firstLast = ' first'; }
   $menu_item_class .= $firstLast;` but it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so you can understand, take a lool at [this code](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6BUG6p).

And more explanation: You have a variable `$class_name` that has, for example, the value `abc`, once it enters the `foreach` and the `$i` IS equals to `0`, `$class_name` is going to be `abc first`. But from now on, you'll keep accessing `$class_name`, which is, guess what, `abc first`.

[This Code](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xiaHSy) is changed to keep the correct value (note that this might not be the best way, but what you need to understand is that once you add `first` to the variable, next time you access it, it's going to be there).

Take a look at the `// ADDED THIS LINE` lines:

```
function social_icons( $menu_item_class='', $icon_class='', $title_class = ''){
    $menu_item_class .= ($title_class != '') ? ' no-title' : '';
    $original_class = $menu_item_class; // ADDED THIS LINE
    $social_network = array(
      0=>  array (
        "title"=> "ello",
        "url"=>"envato"
      ),
      1=> array (
        "title"=> "vk",
        "url"=> "envato"
      ),
      2=> array (
        "title"=> "twitter",
        "url"=> "envato"
      ),
      3=> array (
        "title"=> "lastfm",
        "url"=> "envato"
      )
    ); 
    $social_icon_wrapper = ' string';
    $type = ' string2';
    $count = 4;

    if ( $count > 0 ) { ?>
    <div id="social-network">
        <ul class="social-icons">
        <?php foreach ($social_network as $i=>$sn ){
            // var_dump($i); // this always returns fine
            $menu_item_class = $original_class; // ADDED THIS LINE
            if ( $i == 0 ) { $menu_item_class .= ' first'; } // for some reason this IF is always true
            if ( $i == ($count-1) ) { $menu_item_class .= ' last'; }
            ?>
            <?php if ( $sn['title'] == 'ello' ) { ?> <li class="<?php echo $menu_item_class; ?>"><a class="ello" href="https://ello.co/<?php echo $sn['url']; ?>"><span class="social-icon-wrapper<?php echo $type; ?>"><i class="<?php echo $icon_class; ?> social-ello"></i></span>ello</a></li><?php } ?>
            <?php if ( $sn['title'] == 'vk' ) { ?> <li class="<?php echo $menu_item_class; ?>"><a class="vk" href="https://vk.com/<?php echo $sn['url']; ?>"><span class="social-icon-wrapper<?php echo $type; ?>"><i class="<?php echo $icon_class; ?> social-vk"></i></span>vk</a></li><?php } ?>
            <?php if ( $sn['title'] == 'facebook' ) { ?> <li class="<?php echo $menu_item_class; ?>"><a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/<?php echo $sn['url']; ?>"><span class="social-icon-wrapper<?php echo $type; ?>"><i class="<?php echo $icon_class; ?> social-facebook"></i></span>facebook</a></li><?php } ?>
            <?php if ( $sn['title'] == 'pinterest' ) { ?> <li class="<?php echo $menu_item_class; ?>"><a class="pinterest" href="https://pinterest.com/<?php echo $sn['url']; ?>"><span class="social-icon-wrapper<?php echo $type; ?>"><i class="<?php echo $icon_class; ?> social-pinterest"></i></span>pinterest</a></li><?php } ?>
            <?php if ( $sn['title'] == 'twitter' ) { ?> <li class="<?php echo $menu_item_class; ?>"><a class="twitter" href="https://www.twitter.com/<?php echo $sn['url']; ?>"><span class="social-icon-wrapper<?php echo $type; ?>"><i class="<?php echo $icon_class; ?> social-twitter"></i></span>twitter</a></li><?php } ?>
            <?php if ( $sn['title'] == 'lastfm' ) { ?> <li class="<?php echo $menu_item_class; ?>"><a class="lastfm" href="http://www.last.fm/user/<?php echo $sn['url']; ?>"><span class="social-icon-wrapper<?php echo $type; ?>"><i class="<?php echo $icon_class; ?> social-lastfm"></i></span>lastfm</a></li><?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>      
        </ul>
    </div>

    <?php } 
}
social_icons();
```

Comment: So the `$menu_item_class` needs to be cached and reset inside the loop. I think this is different with Javascript. Thank you so much.

Comment: Basically, yes. You could do the opposite and change the other variable instead (I did it this way because I'm lazy and I didn't want to look for every occurrence of `$menu_item_class`). Anyway, main issue: you changed the value of the variable, so every successive access to it would bring the new value (with `first`) not the original one (without `first`). Note that the condition is true only once.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$class_name ='';
if ($i == 0) { $class_name = ' first'; }
```

Comment: Lol, his code is not really clear, might do might not.

Comment: Ok, this IS GOING TO erase what is already inside `$class_name`. If you take a look at the question ([pen](http://codepad.viper-7.com/poZ3jU) link more specifically), you'll see that this variable (that seems to be with a different name - `$menu_item_class`) comes from a function parameter and might contain a value. No rudeness intended ^^

Comment: @FirstOne, that is true. Still thanks again to all of you who reacted.